# Managing multiple instances of views in one page apps using Routes in Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am working on a single-page app using Backbone.js.  An issue that has occurred to me is that since one is not reloading the page, that when one creates a instance of a View, then I assume, that the View object will remain in memory for the life of the app. This does not seem very efficient to me, since a particular view may no longer be needed if another route is called. However, a particular View may later need to be 'displayed' if one returns to that original route. So the question is, how to best manage views in Backbone with regards to routes?

In my app, many of the views are responsible for displaying a particular 'page' and as such share the same DOM element.  When one of these 'page' views is called, it will replace the content in the DOM element previously put in place by the previous view.  Thus the previous view is no longer needed.

Do I need to somehow manually destroy the previous View (or is this somehow handled by the Router object)?  Or is it better to leave the views once they have been initialized?

Following sample code shows how views instances are being creating in the Router in the app.

```js
/** 
 * View - List of contacts 
 */    
var ListContactsView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: '#content',
  template: _.template($('#list-contacts-tpl').html()),
  initialize: function() {
    _.bindAll(this, 'render');
    this.collection = new Contacts();
    this.collection.bind('reset', this.render);
    this.collection.fetch();
  },
  render: function() {
    this.$el.hide();
    this.$el.html(this.template({ contacts: this.collection }));
    this.$el.fadeIn(500);
  }
});

/** 
 * View - Display single contact 
 */
var DisplayContactView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: '#content',
  events: {
    'click #delete-contact-button': 'deleteContact'
  },
  template: _.template($('#display-contact-tpl').html()),
  initialize: function() {
    _.bindAll(this, 'deleteContact', 'render');
    // Create reference to event aggregator object.
    if (typeof this.options.id === 'undefined') {
      throw new Error('View DisplayContactView initialized without _id parameter.');
    }
    this.model = new Contact({ _id: this.options.id });
    // Add parse method since parsing is not done by collection in this 
    // instance, as this model is not called in the scope of collection 
    // Contacts.
    this.model.parse = function(response) {
      return response.data;
    };
    this.model.bind('change', this.render);
    this.model.fetch();
  },
  deleteContact: function(id) {
    // Trigger deleteContact event.
    this.eventAggregator.trigger('deleteContact', id);
  },
  render: function() {
    this.$el.html(this.template({ contact: this.model.attributes }));
  }
});

/**
 * Page routes
 */
var $content = $('#content');
var ClientSideRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
  routes: {
    'browse': 'browse',
    'browse/view/:id': 'browseViewContact',
    'orgs': 'orgs',
    'orgs/:orgName': 'orgs',
    'orgs/:orgName/:id': 'orgs',
    'contact/add': 'addContact',
    'contact/view/:id': 'viewContact',
    'contact/delete/:id': 'confirmDelete',
    '*path': 'defaultPage'
  },
  addContact: function() {
    // Display contact edit form.
    var editContactFormView = new EditContactFormView();
    // Display email field in edit form.
  },
  browse: function() {
    var listContactsView = new ListContactsView();
  },
  browseViewContact: function(id) {
    var displayContactView = new DisplayContactView({ id: id });
  },
  defaultPage: function(path) {
    $content.html('Default');
  },
  home: function() {
    $content.html('Home');
  },
  viewContact: function(id) {
    $.ajax({
      url: '/contact/view/' + id,
      dataType: 'html',
      success: function(data) {
        $content.html(data);
      }
    });
  }
});

var clientSideRouter = new ClientSideRouter();
Backbone.history.start();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Backbone.js has no built in support for view compositions, there are several patterns that you could follow when it comes to keeping track of child views.

- Derick Bailey illustrates extending Backbone.View to allow views to
  clean up after themselves -
  http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/09/15/zombies-run-managing-page-transitions-in-backbone-apps/
- Another alternative is to add on child views to a property of the
  parent view and manually clean them up when the parent view state is
  removed.

  var ParentView = Backbone.View.extend({
      initialize : function(){
         this.childViews = [];
      },
      render: function(){
         this.childViews.push(new ChildView);
      }
  });
- A third alternative is to make the child views subscribe to events
  that the parent views trigger, so that they can clean up when the
  parent view publishes a "close" event.

Also I noticed from your code that you are actually fetching a model within your child view class. Ideally, I would suggest passing the model as a parameter to the constructor as this decouples the view from the data. It's more MVC-ish

Answer (score 2):

- Routes do not destroy views

Routes provide you convenient manner to interact with url changes. By convenience i mean url semantics and context of current page. For example url `#/!/create/` will invoke a method that should display a form to create a model. Context here is the view to create model.

- Views should be managed by the developer

there still does not exists a well known manner to manage views in Backbone.js, but i prefer the way of **global variables**. This would ensure your view instances are available throughout application and all the modules have access to them. For example doing this

`window.App.Contacts.ContactView = new App.Contacts.View.ContactView({model:BenContact});`   will make view used to display Ben's contact information available to application modules through window object. All you need to do for any views that use same `el` is to destroy the `ContactView` and render the new view.

- You have methods on view to remove them

[Undelegate](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-undelegateEvents) Events and [Remove](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-remove) methods help you remove them. Inside the callback method that handles routes hash change events. For example in the callback method that handles `#/!/view/all` ( url to view all the contacts list) you might come across situation where both the views now use the same `el` so you should destroy the `ContactView` and render `ListView` so in the callback do this

`App.Contacts.ContactView.undelegateEvents();`

`App.Contacts.ContactView.remove();`